# php add or subtract timezone offset

Tags: php, timezone-offset

I have some dates stored in gmt in a mysql db.
Say the clients timezone offset was -540; how would I correct the `datetime` coming from the database to reflect that? Is there a handy function I can put the date through, or am I going to need to add or subtract accordingly.

Comment: Use `timestamp` mysql data type and mysql will do that for you

Comment: How can it do that? It doesn't know the clients timezone surely. I guess it will do it based on the server timezone no? I'm all ears - thanks.

Comment: you can set the client timezone for each connection and mysql will do all offset work for you. There are million discussions about it here on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have the data items in GMT format, you will have to convert them to time stamps, using `strtotime`, more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
Once you have the time stamp, you can subtract the offset (540 times 60 seconds) from it, and then convert the result to a new date string, using `date`, more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Here is one version of the code that could to this:

```
$dbValue = $row['date']; 
$timestamp = strtotime($dbValue) - (540*60);
$result = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks - what would be the pros and cons of me changing the field to a type of timestamp in the database. At this point it's an option if it would serve me better.

Comment: I think we're on the right track with this. However the code above takes of 9 mins not 9 hours.

Comment: Of the top of my head, I have to say one con would be the fact that to display them throughout your project, you would have to convert the time stamps to date strings, but I can't think of any other cons. Pros, you can sort the rows by date very easily, since time stamps are basically numbers. And you can make relative calculations easier, like in your initial question. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you say it takes 9 mins, instead of 9 hours, you can get the offset by using strtotime again, like this: $offset = strtotime("-9 hours"); And subtract that value from the original time stamp. Let us know if it works

Comment: Thanks Romi. Ended up doing this - 540*60;    I'll mark this correct.

Comment: Glad I could help:) Have a great.

Comment: This would fail for leap hours (though this is probably still what OP wants)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this Snippet will help you:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$obj = new DateTime();
$date = date($format, strtotime($obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - $obj->format('Z'));
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php for further readings.