# PHP - MYSQL timezone - add additional hours before echo-ing rows

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I have a MySQL table called temperature

One of my attribute is called "now"
It shows the timestamp on the server.

Schema:

```
now (current_time), id (auto increment), temp (varchar 50)
```

Example of now attributes

```
2018-06-07 11:19:46
2018-06-08 02:06:12
```

I do not have access to change the time on the server.

Upon reading the now values, how do I add 5.5 hours to now?

My current code to read now

```
$sql = "SELECT id, now, temp FROM temperature";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Time: " . $row["now"]. " . - Temperature: ". $row["temp"]. "<br>";
  }

 } else {
echo "no data";
 }
```

Is this possible? Can I add 5.5 hours before echo-ing?

Comment: Yes you can. Use strtotime and date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php add or subtract timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580394/php-add-or-subtract-timezone-offset)

Comment: What datatype is used in your 'temperature` table for your `now` column? `DATETIME`?  `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @O.Jones see code part below `Example of now attributes` in question

Comment: "Can I add 5.5 hours before echo-ing?" with 5.5 hours you mean 5 hour and 30 minutes i assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MYSQL's ADDTIME function in query.

```
SELECT id, ADDTIME(now, "5:30:0") AS now_added FROM temprature;
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your question involves the [Indian national time zone (+5:30)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist). That time zone's name in the [zoneinfo database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) is `Asia/Kolkata`.

I guess from your question that you are trying to convert times from U[niversal Time Coordinated (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) to Indian Time.

It matters whether your `now` attribute is stored in your table as a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column. Your question does not show enough information for us to know that; both data types render with text strings like `2018-07-08 13:31:20`.

If your `now` attribute is a `TIMESTAMP` you have a good situation. Why? MySQL stores `TIMESTAMP` values with reference to Universal Time Coordinated. So all you need to do is set the timezone of your MySQL connection, then do your select query, by running these two queries one after the other, with separate calls to the `query()` method.

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
SELECT id, now, temp FROM temperature;
```

MySQL will convert your `now` values to Indian Time.

If your `now` column has the `DATETIME` datatype, it means the data in your table is stored without reference to any time zone. In that case you can use this query to convert those values from UTC to Indian time.

```
 SELECT id, CONVERT_TZ(now,'UTC','Asia/Kolkata') AS now, temp FROM temperature
```

In order to use MySQL's time zone support, you may need to populate your server's time zone tables. Tell your server administrator to do that, or look at this page for instructions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score -3):

look at this sample code using function strtotime and date 
just add that before echoing
example:

```
  $selectedTime = $row['now'];
  $endTime = date("H:i:s" ,strtotime("+5 hours 50 minutes", strtotime($selectedTime)));
  echo $endTime;
```

Comment: `"$row['now']"` what is this?

Comment: @RaymondNijland since it's enclosed in `"` it should return a string value of the array item. But the `"` are not needed, not should they do any harm.

Comment: I know what it is and how it executes. I meant with "what is this?" more like "omg!!!"..String interpolation is a bad programming habit in PHP also it executes slower (not much but slower) then non string interpolation

Comment: as i was writting I have forgotten to delete those enclose " " ... but the main point is in the second line. $selectedTime is just for choosing a time so if you have that in exact in hours minutes then you need those enclosed  " " ... I have deleted them in my example like I said above I have forgotten to delete them.